# How to install older version of create-react-app through pnpx?

Tags: reactjs, pnpm

When I type this code

```
 pnpx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

Output screen

```
✔ Install the following package: create-react-app@latest? (Y/n) · false
Cancelled
```

If I type 'n' it not install.
If I type 'y' it install create-react-app for latest version with 50 - 60 MB data.

I don't want create-react-app with latest version.
I want to use already cache create-react-app in my computer which always happen when I install through pnpm package manager.

Whenever create-react-app update there package pnpx always asking me to install latest version when I told no it not install for older version.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

First, go to the `package.json` file and change the version of `react`, `react-dom`, and `react-scripts` to the desired version.

Next, clear the `node_modules` and the `package-lock.json` file.

Finally, hit:

```
npm install
```